# Need help to convert older code to version 5

Tags: pine-script

I'm very new to pine script and need help to convert this old version code to version 5.
Appreciate if somebody can help me.

```
ma50 = sma(close, 50)
ma200 = sma(close, 200)
bgcolor (close > ma50 and ma50 > ma200 and ma50[1] <= ma200[1] ? gray:na, transp=20)
```

I'm not able to use converter for old script

Comment: See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/14853083)

Comment: Please edit your question, format it correctly and explain what you try

Answer (score -1):

```
// Pine Script v5
study("My Indicator")
color = input(true, "Color")
ma50 = sma(close, 50)
ma200 = sma(close, 200)
gray = #808080
bgcolor(close > ma50 and ma50 > ma200 and ma50[1] <= ma200[1] ? gray : na, transp=20)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.